# React Native rendering same route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to change routes on button press in React Native. In my SplashContainer component this is the method I'm running:

```js
handleToSignUp = () => {
    console.log("Running handleToSignUp")
    this.props.navigator.push({
        signUpForm: true
    });
}
```

My Navigator component looks like this

```js
export default class NimbusNavigator extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        isAuthed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
    }
    renderScene = (route, navigator) => {
        console.log(route);
        console.log(navigator);
        // Keeps track of whether user is Authed or not. 
        if (this.props.isAuthed === false && route !== 'signUpForm') {
            return <SplashContainer navigator={navigator}/>
        } else if (route === 'signUpForm') {
            return <SignUpForm navigator={navigator} />
        }

        return <FooterTabsContainer navigator={navigator} />
    }
    configureScene = (route) => {
        return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <Navigator
                configureScene={this.configureScene}
                renderScene={this.renderScene}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

If `route` is not equal to `'signUpForm'` shouldn't code skip to the `else if` statement and render `<SignUpForm/>` component?

Thanks!

Comment: Which navigator are you using? Also, keep in mind that React Native core is changing its navigator some time this month (January 2016)

Comment: One other thing, do you have an `initialRoute` declared?

Comment: I'm using the Navigator from react-native.

Comment: @NaderDabit I don't have an initial route declared. For the pre-splash and splash containers I was just rendering those based on wheter the user was authed or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to get this working, but the main thing to remember is that everything passed to `navigator.push({ // properties of the route object })` become properties of the route object.

For instance, if you keep your `handleSignUp` method the way it is, you would need to rewrite your `renderScene` method like so:

```
renderScene = (route, navigator) => {
    if (this.props.isAuthed === false && !route.signUpForm) {
        return <SplashContainer navigator={navigator}/>
    } else if (route.signUpForm) {
        return <SignUpForm navigator={navigator} />
    }

    return <FooterTabsContainer navigator={navigator} />
}
```

You could also rewrite your `handleSignUp` method like this:

```
handleToSignUp = () => {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        title: 'handleSignUpForm'
    });
}
```

And `renderScene` like this:

```
renderScene = (route, navigator) => {
    if (this.props.isAuthed === false && route.title !== 'signUpForm') {
        return <SplashContainer navigator={navigator}/>
    } else if (route.title === 'signUpForm') {
        return <SignUpForm navigator={navigator} />
    }

    return <FooterTabsContainer navigator={navigator} />
}
```

Comment: I'm writing the code like I am currently because route was being `console.log` as `undefined` which I don't even know how that is possible.

Comment: I think you need an `initialRoute`